# Multiple texts output according to multiple values in 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, multiple-columns, nested-loops

I am starting to code in `python` (`Pandas` library) because of my work.
Here is an example with pokemons but my real `dataframe` is more complex. I dont know if it's possible to do it in Pandas.

My `dataframe` is like:

```
   Pokemon_Master      Pokemon 
1   ASH                pikachu
2   ASH                squirtle
3   ASH                charmander
4   BROOKE             onix
5   BROOKE             charmander
6   MISTY              squirtle
7   MISTY              charmander
8   GARY               onix 
9   PROF OAK           pikachu
```

**What I have to do is:** to check which Pokemon_Master each Pokemon belongs too and make a `.txt` output for each Pokemon_Master in the following format: *Ash_pokemons.txt* or *Brooke_pokemons.txt*, etc. Each file has to contain the pokemons which each Master has, e.g. each `.txt` file will concatenate progressively with the previous one as they are discovering pokemons in the `dataframe`.
Also the output text file will be called based on the Pokemon_Master.
For example:
Inside the file *ASH.txt*

```
pikachu 
squirtle
charmander
```

and Inside the file *BROOKE.txt*

```
onix 
charmander  
squirtle
```

etc..

I have discovered lots of basic functions like `loc`, `iterrows` `concatenate` or `append` (for joining files), but I cannot find the way how to join all of this to develop my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, try:

```
for n, g in df.groupby('Pokemon_Master'):
    g[['Pokemon']].agg(' '.join).to_csv(f'{n}.txt', sep=' ', 
                                        index=False, 
                                        header=False)
```

If Python version less than 3.6:

Try,

```
for n, g in df.groupby('Pokemon_Master'):
    g[['Pokemon']].agg(' '.join).to_csv('{}.txt'.format(n), sep=' ', 
                                        index=False, 
                                        header=False)
```

Comment: thank you so much Scott, I tried to apply it in my code, but it gave me error; I think is because I dont have 'f' defined:                                                                                             File "<ipython-input-12-64ac54608df7>", line 2
    g[['error']].agg(' '.join).to_csv(f'{n}.txt'), sep=' ', index=False, header=False)
                                                                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: What version of python are you using?  f is f-string formatting in Python 3.6+.

Comment: thanks again, it works now! really i need to improve my skills, i dont know if you have some recommendations for studying this, for example, Why you used [[ ]] ? and join and agg methods?. Thanks again

Comment: I used the double brackets to make selecting the column as  a dataframe instead of a series.  This will slightly change the way 'agg' works with ' '.join in this case.   My recommendation is a website called ['Dunder Data'](https://www.dunderdata.com/) run by the guy who taught me pandas a few years ago.  @TedPetrou